# Commented games for beginners

Tags: beginner, annotation

I'm looking for a website where we can find annotated games for beginners. I mean games with basic comments and lenght of the game is short.
The best would be that we can see the pieces moving but kind of optional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YouTube is a good resource to consider.  There is one user in particular that annotates miniatures rather well for beginners, and as a bonus, he sounds like Dracula.

https://www.youtube.com/user/MatoJelic

Comment: Yeah, I also thought of youtube, Daniel King is quite accessible, though maybe not for absolute beginners.

Comment: Mato is the best, he makes chess very exciting. But the audio of a lot of his videos is super low up. I'd love to fly out to Croatia and teach him a little about audio engineering.